# Probability of an edge in directed random configuration graph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs

I am considering Bollobas' directed random configuration graph of size $N$, constructed by the following random algorithm:

1. Draw a sequence of $N$ node-degree pairs $(j_1,k_1),...,(j_N,k_N)$ independently from the degree distribution $P$.
   Accept the draw only if it is feasible, i.e. only if $\sum_{n \in [N]}(j_n-k_n)=0$.
2. For every node $n$, create $j_n$ in-stubs and $k_n$ out-stubs, where in-/out-stubs are open ended half-edges with an in-/out-arrow.
3. For any unpaired out-stub, select iteratively uniformly at random an unpaired in-stub and connect them.

Each such resulting pair of stubs forms a directed edge of the graph.

I am interested in the probabilities of an edge. My suggestion is:

Under this random matching approach, the probability that there is an edge from a node $i$ to a node $l$ is, with $m$ being the number of all edges:
$$p_{il}=\frac{k_i \cdot j_l}{(2m-1)},$$
as node $i$ has $k_i$ out-stubs and $j_l$ in-stubs out of $2m-1$ (excluding of node $i$) attached to $l$ to which it could connect.

And similarly the probability that there is an edge from a node $l$ to $i$ is:$$p_{il}=\frac{j_i \cdot k_l}{(2m-1)}$$

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can choose a uniformly random matching in any order. So let's choose the $k_i$ edges out of node $i$ one at a time and see the probability *none* of them go to node $l$.

The first edge we choose has probability $\frac{j_l}{m}$ of going to $l$. If it doesn't, then the second edge has probability $\frac{j_l}{m-1}$. If that also doesn't happen, then the third edge has probability $\frac{j_l}{m-2}$, and so on. So the overall probability that none of the edges go to node $l$ is
$$
   1-p_{il} = \left(1 - \frac{j_l}{m}\right)\left(1 - \frac{j_l}{m-1}\right) \dotsb \left(1 - \frac{j_l}{m-k_i+1}\right)
$$
and the probability you want is the complement of this one.

*Asymptotically*, however, assuming $k_i$ and $j_l$ are small relative to $m$, the answer is in fact close to $\frac{k_i \cdot j_l}{m}$ which is what you have, except that $m$ and not $2m-1$ is the number of options for the first edge. (Unlike the undirected configuration model, here there are $m$ out-stubs and $m$ in-stubs, which we distinguish.)

Additionally, because there are $k_i$ edges with probability $\frac{j_l}{m}$ of going to $l$, then $\frac{k_i j_l}{m}$ edges is the expected number of edges from $i$ to $l$.

Comment: So I guess there is no "neat" form for the probability as in the undirected one, where it is of the form $p_{ij} =\frac{ k_i k_j} {2m−1}$. ? (Only for the large limits as you stated $p_{il} =\frac{ k_i j_l} {m}$)

Comment: The "neat" form is not the probability but the expected number of edges from $i$ to $l$.

Comment: And for the undirected case, the formula you give is also the expectation, not the probability.

Comment: This is what I read in following paper concerning the undirected model (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a542/b2f978f0bae988aa881bf566872f0e2e73cd.pdf) page 5. So the paper is not correct? Or what I am missing?

Comment: The paper does not use the configuration mode. Instead, they define $p_{ij} = \frac{k_i k_j}{2m}$ then add an edge $ij$ with that probability. As they mention on p. 3 (second paragraph) the actual degree of vertex $i$ is not guaranteed to be $k_i$ in this model.

Comment: Upon further reading, the paper does seem to claim that $\frac{k_i k_j}{2m-1}$ is the exact edge probability in the random matching model, which is incorrect.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, you write: "the formula you give is also the expectation, not the probability." But aren't the probability and the expected number of edges between nodes $i$ and $l$ the same for the undirected case? Because: the probability for one specific edge stub of node $i$ to connect to any edge stub of node $l$ is given by: $\approx \frac{k_l}{2m}$; there are $k_i$ edge stubs on node $i$, so $p(i,l) = \frac{k_i k_l}{2m}$ should be the probability that any edge stub of $i$ connects to any edge stub of $l$, right? At the same time, it is the expected number of edges between these two nodes.

Comment: @Splines In the configuration model, we are able to end up creating multiple edges between two nodes.

Comment: Ok, but doesn't that back up my statement? As that means that the probability for two edge stubs on nodes $i$ and $l$ to connect is given by $\frac{1}{2m-1}$ all the time (uniformly). Hence, the probability that a specific edge stub of $i$ connects to any edge stub of $l$ is $\frac{k_l}{2m-1}$. As vertex $i$ has $k_i$ edge stubs, the probability that *any* edge stub of $i$ connects to any edge stub of $l$ in the random graph is then: $p(i,l) \overset{?}{=} \frac{k_i k_l}{2m-1} = \mathbb{E}[X_i^l]$ given your definition of $X$ from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3676623/1083321).

Comment: @Splines These are not disjoint events, so you cannot add up their probabilities to get the total probability that any edge stub of $i$ connects to any edge stub of $l$.

Comment: Wow, sometimes it's so simple. Thanks a lot, that clarified it for me. Gonna have to correct that [here](https://splines.github.io/fast-louvain/modularity/formula.html#configuration-model--modularity-formula)