# Edge probability and expected number of edges in the configuration model

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs, network

This question is related to question: [Probability that exists at least an edge in the configuration model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733195/probability-that-exists-at-least-an-edge-in-the-configuration-model)

There is something I do not understand about the computation of the *expected number of edges between $i$ and $j$ nodes in the configurational model*, $p_{ij}$. The argument given everywhere I've seen is:

1. There are $2m$ stubs in the network, with $k_i$ in node $i$ and $k_j$ in node $j$.
2. Taking one stub from node $i$, there are $k_j$ possible stubs to connect it to node $j$, so the probability to connect it to node $j$ is $\frac{k_j}{2m-1}$, the $2m-1$ because you can not connect it to the same stub you are coming from.
3. There are $k_i$ stubs in node i, so the expected number of edges is just adding up the different probabilities and $p_{ij} = k_i \times \frac{k_j}{2m-1}$.

**I do not understand step 3.** I would think once there has been an edge between nodes $i$ and $j$, the probability to connect the next stub should change accordingly because there is one less available stub at node $j$: $\frac{k_j-1}{2m-3}$. But also, each new stub considered in node $i$ has two less possible stubs to be connected (because every other edge already connected has two stub ends), so the total available edges in the denominator should decrease as well: $2m-3$, $2m-5$, ..., $2m-2k_i-1$.

**Instead, I'd proceed in this way:**
$$p_{ij} = 1 - \bar{p}_{ij}, $$
where $\bar{p}_{ij}$ is the probability there isn't any edge between nodes $i$ and $j$. Then,
$$\bar{p}_{ij} = \bar{p}_{{i_1}j} \times \bar{p}_{{i_2}j}\times \dots  \times \bar{p}_{{i_{k_i}}j}, $$
where $\bar{p}_{{i_1}j}$ is the probability there isn't an edge between the first stub in node $i$ to node $j$ and $\bar{p}_{{i_1}j} = \frac{2m-1-k_j}{2m-1}$. Analogously for the other stubs, we get
$$\bar{p}_{ij} = \frac{2m-1-k_j}{2m-1}  \frac{2m-3-k_j}{2m-3} \dots \frac{2m-2k_i-1-k_j}{2m-2k_i-1} = \left( 1 - \frac{k_j}{2m-1} \right)   \left( 1 - \frac{k_j}{2m-3} \right)  \dots \left( 1 - \frac{k_j}{2m-2k_i-1} \right).  $$

So
$$p_{ij} = 1- \left( 1 - \frac{k_j}{2m-1} \right)   \left( 1 - \frac{k_j}{2m-3} \right)  ... \left( 1 - \frac{k_j}{2m-2k_i-1} \right).$$

I can recover from this expression the other one in the large number of edges limit $m \to \infty$, then $2m-2k_i-1 \simeq ... \simeq 2m - 3 \simeq 2m - 1$ and
$$p_{ij} \simeq 1- \left( 1 - \frac{k_j}{2m-1} \right)^{k_i} \simeq 1 - \left( 1 - \frac{k_i k_j}{2m-1} \right) = \frac{k_i k_j}{2m-1},$$
where in the second step I have used the series expansion $(1 - x)^a = 1 - ax + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$ for $x \to 0$.

**Question:** Does this mean that only the expected number of edges between $i$ and $j$ nodes in the configurational model is $p_{ij} = \frac{k_i k_j}{2m-1}$ in the large number of edges $m$ limit? If that is the case, I find it strange because they don't specify it in any of the sources I've looked. Instead, they seem to say $p_{ij} = \frac{k_i k_j}{2m-1}$ is the general expression which in the large number of edges limit becomes $p_{ij} = \frac{k_i k_j}{2m}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The difference between your calculation and the standard one

Actually, $\frac{k_i k_j}{2m-1}$ is the exact **expected number of edges** between nodes $i$ and $j$.

When you compute
$$
   1 - \bar{p}_{{i_1}j} \times \bar{p}_{{i_2}j}\times \dots  \times \bar{p}_{{i_{k_i}}j}
$$
you are computing something different: the **probability** that there is at least one edge between $i$ and $j$. (That's because the product $\bar{p}_{{i_1}j} \times \bar{p}_{{i_2}j}\times \dots  \times \bar{p}_{{i_{k_i}}j}$ gives the probability that there are no edges.)

However, in the configuration model, it's possible that there are multiple parallel edges between nodes $i$ and $j$. So the expected number of edges will be bigger than the probability that there is at least one edge.

With typical values (but not all values) of $k_i$, $k_j$, and $m$, it's very unlikely that there are multiple edges between $i$ and $j$: much less likely than having one edge. In that setting, the two values are very close, which is what you're seeing.

### The expected value calculation, spelled out

Here's a more detailed justification for the expected value calculation. Number the stubs at node $i$ from $1$ to $k_i$, and number the stubs at node $j$ from $1$ to $k_j$. For $1 \le a \le k_i$ and $1 \le b \le k_j$, define the random variable $X_{i,a}^{j,b}$ to be $1$ if we join the $a^{\text{th}}$ stub at $i$ to the $b^{\text{th}}$ stub at $j$. Let $X_i^j$ be the number of edges between $i$ and $j$. Then
$$
    X_i^j = \sum_{a=1}^{k_i} \sum_{b=1}^{k_j} X_{i,a}^{j,b}
$$
and therefore
$$
   \mathbb E[X_i^j] = \sum_{a=1}^{k_i} \sum_{b=1}^{k_j} \mathbb E[X_{i,a}^{j,b}].
$$
Here we use linearity of expectation, which doesn't care that the random variables $X_{i,a}^{j,b}$ are dependent.

Finally, we have $\mathbb E[X_{i,a}^{j,b}] = \frac1{2m-1}$ for any $a$ and $b$. This doesn't care about what any of the other stubs are doing, because this is a calculation for only one pair of stubs. Therefore $\mathbb E[X_i^j] = \frac{k_i k_j}{2m-1}$ because we add up $k_i k_j$ equal terms.

### How to think about these expected values

Regarding the calculation of $\mathbb E[X_{i,a}^{j,b}] = \frac1{2m-1}$: here is how to think about this, and related calculations, painlessly.

We have a randomizing algorithm for generating a graph from the configuration model:

1. **Pick one** of the $2m$ stubs. Choose another one of the $2m-1$ stubs uniformly at random, and connect them.
2. **Pick one** of the $2m-2$ remaining disconnected stubs. Choose one of the $2m-3$ other stubs uniformly at random, and connect them.
3. Repeat until all stubs are connected. Then do the configuration-model-to-graph operation which is irrelevant for now.

This is actually a family of algorithms. In the $i^{\text{th}}$ step, we **pick one** of the $2m-2i$ remaining stubs, *in a way I haven't specified*, and then pick one of the $2m-2i-1$ other remaining stubs uniformly at random. We can **pick the first stub** in many ways: at random, or going in a fixed order, or whatever.

The key fact you should convince yourself of is that no matter how we do that, we end up getting one of the $(2m-1)(2m-3)\dotsm (5)(3)(1)$ matchings of the $2m$ stubs uniformly at random. That means that the way we **pick one** of $2m-2i$ stubs in the $i^{\text{th}}$ step doesn't matter, and we can do whichever thing is most convenient for us.

When computing $\mathbb E[X_{i,a}^{j,b}]$, the most convenient rule to use is "In the first step, **pick the $a^{\text{th}}$ stub** out of node $i$ to connect to a uniformly random stub. In the other steps, do whatever." With this rule, it's clear that $\mathbb E[X_{i,a}^{j,b}] = \frac1{2m-1}$.

The rule we use shouldn't change the calculation of $\mathbb E[X_{i,a}^{j,b}]$. Therefore it's fine that we use a different rule for every $a$ and for every $b$. If we had to use the same rule for every $a$ and $b$, we'd still get $\frac1{2m-1}$ for all of them, but the calculation would be more painful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am still somewhat confused though... Imagine the way we draw the edges is we follow always increasing values of $a$ of a node, so we don't draw stub $a$ before $1, \dots, a-1$ stubs (and the corresponding other stub ends), then shouldn't it be $\mathbb E[X_{i,a}^{j,b}] = \frac{1}{2m-2a}$?

Comment: The reason $\mathbb E[X_{i,a}^{j,b}] = \frac1{2m-1}$ is that there are $(2m-1)(2m-3)(2m-3) \cdots (3)(1)$ ways to connect all $2m$ stubs, and $(2m-3)(2m-5) \cdots (3)(1)$ to connect the stubs if $(i,a)$ and $(j,b)$ are connected. Dividing these gets $\frac1{2m-1}$.

Comment: You could think of it as connecting the stubs one at a time in the order you specify, but then $\mathbb E[X_{i,a}^{j,b}]$ becomes much harder to compute. Some of the time, none of the $2(a-1)$ previous stubs we connected were $(i,a)$ or $(j,b)$, in which case the probability is $\frac1{2m-2a-1}$. But in other cases, we already connected one of the previous $a-1$ stubs to $(i,a)$ and/or $(j,b)$, in which case the probability is $0$. The correct probability is $p \cdot \frac1{2m-2a-1} + (1-p) \cdot 0$, where $p$ is the probability that $(i,a)$ and $(j,b)$ haven't been touched yet.

Comment: So then $\mathbb E[X_{i,a}^{j,b}]$ depends on the implementation details? That's what I find confusing... I understand in the large number of edges limit you don't get multiedges or self-edges so all of them become the original expression?

Comment: It doesn't depend on the implementation details, but it gets easier or harder to compute it. If we find the probability $p$ in the calculation above, it will be exactly $\frac{2m-3}{2m-1} \cdot \frac{2m-5}{2m-3} \cdots \frac{2m-2a-1}{2m-2a+1}$, and the whole thing simplifies to $\frac1{2m-1}$ again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your "spelled out" calculation of the expected value. I have used this in my [new video](https://youtu.be/Xt0vBtBY2BU?t=1265) about community detection.